# Disable copy paste in SWT Text Component

Tags: text, copy, swt, paste

I'm using SWT Text component. Do someone know how can I prevent copy/paste operation for the Text component.

Thanks
Subha

Comment: okay, now I'm curious.. why?????

Answer (score 0):

A crude way of doing this would be to disable the control-key modifier on the Text box.

```
    text.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.stateMask == 262144) {
                event.doit = false;
            }

        }
    });
```

Plus you may also want to disable the right click on the text box (use a MouseListener with the same trick).

Answer (score 0):

I done this by simply setting my own menu with no menu items at all.

```
      ((Text) textFirstNameEntry).setMenu(new Menu(shell, 0));
```